# Variable number of decimal places in Double to String ValueConverter

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, string-formatting, ivalueconverter

I created a ValueConverter between `Double` and `String` so that my textboxes have a given number of decimal places.

I need, though, to be able to pass an integer as a parameter to the ValueConverter methods, so that I can have a different number of decimal places on any given textbox, and yet use the same converter.

My converter code is here:

```
[ValueConversion(typeof(Double), typeof(String))]
public class DoubleToStringPontoVirgula : IValueConverter {

    // Converte um double em uma string separada por vírgula com tantas casas depois da vírgula
    public object Convert(object value,
                          Type targetType,
                          object parameter, // I would like to use this!!
                          System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {

        string resultado = string.Format("{0:0.0}", // Shouldn't be a hardcoded format!
                                           value);
        return resultado;

    }

    // Converte uma string separada por ponto OU vírgula em um double
    public object ConvertBack(object value,
                              Type targetType,
                              object parameter,
                              System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) {

        string entrada = value as string;

        double resultado = System.Convert.ToDouble(entrada.Replace('.', ','));

        return resultado;

    }

}
```

In the XAML, I would like to pass the parameter like this (using "2" places as example):

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Peso, Converter={StaticResource DoubleToStringPontoVirgula}, ConverterParameter=2}"/>
```

The question is: "How can I take the integer passed as `parametar` argument and use it as the number of decimal places in the string-formatting expression?"

Comment: And your problem is.......?

Comment: Why have a converter at all? You could use the [StringFormat](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat.aspx) property instead.

Comment: why do you need converter... why dont directly specify StringFormat on binding?

Comment: The converter is most necessary because I want the user to input decimal places either using "." or ",". The `ConvertBack` ended up being necessary, so I am using both `Convert` and `ConvertBack` for the tweaking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a format string with the desired number of zeroes:

```
string.Format(culture, "{0:0." + new string('0', Convert.ToInt32(parameter)) + "}"
```

Comment: This worked! I didn't knew that `String` constructor you used. Thanks!